# convert numbers to letters in a data.frame

Tags: r, string, replace, numbers, letters

In R, I have some matrices of numbers and I am going to convert each number to its equivalent letter; 1 to "a", 2 to "b", and so on.

Assume this is the matrix:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:16,12,T),nrow=3,ncol=4))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  5 15 16  1
#2  6  4 11  4
#3 10 15 11  3
```

This is the expected output:

```
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  e  o  p  a
#2  f  d  k  d
#3  j  o  k  c
```

I used `letters[x]` and `letters[list(x)]` but it gave this

> Error in letters[list(x)] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `sapply` is also possible:

```
sapply(x, function(i) letters[i])
#      X1  X2  X3  X4 
# [1,] "e" "o" "p" "a"
# [2,] "f" "d" "k" "d"
# [3,] "j" "o" "k" "c"
```

Answer (score 4):

After converting the 'x' to `matrix`, use that as index for the built-in `letters` and assign it to the original dataset

```
x[] <- letters[as.matrix(x)]
x
#   X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  e  o  p  a
#2  f  d  k  d
#3  j  o  k  c
```

---

Or this can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
   mutate_all(funs(letters[.]))
```

Answer (score 3):

First convert the data frame to a plain vector and then it can be used to subscript `letters`.  Then replace the contents of `x` with that vector.  By using `replace` we can avoid overwriting the original `x`.

```
replace(x, TRUE, letters[unlist(x)])
```

giving:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  e  o  p  a
2  f  d  k  d
3  j  o  k  c
```